# What does it mean for something to be extracted from islands?

Tags: syntax

So I understand that something like a complex NP is an island. And some languages are "sensitive to islands" but what does that mean? What is being extracted from the island and why would you extract something from it?

Comment: Your understanding is probably flawed if you've never heard of syntactic movement transformations, like question formation: _The man asked about **who**?_ ==> _**Who** did the man ask about?_  This and other movement rules can't move words out of certain structures, which are called islands. Phrases starting with _the claim that_ are islands, and you can't question things inside them: *_Who did John doubt the claim that the man asked about?_ Details are in [Ross's dissertation](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Ross_1967.html).

Comment: @jlawler Is that really just an island issue? Even without movement, ‘*the claim that John asked about whom[?]’ is nonsensical, since a question cannot be a claim and vice versa. Conversely, extracting to a relativiser just about works for me: “The book which John doubted the claim that Bill asked about” to me is convoluted, but grammatical – though I suspect others would add an extra ‘it’ at the end, in line with normal island behaviour.

Comment: I was afraid that would happen. If you want to formulate questions without movement rules, go right ahead. Whether Wh-words get inserted as part of the rule or not is not really important, and derivations have more than one step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To illustrate complex NP islands, here is an example of a grammatical wh-question (1) and an ungrammatical wh-question (2) (based on @jlawler's example in their comment):

1. Who<sub>1</sub> did John doubt [<sub>S'</sub> that Mary claimed [<sub>S'</sub> that the man asked about __<sub>1</sub> ] ] ?
2. *Who<sub>1</sub> did John doubt [<sub>NP</sub> Mary's claim [<sub>S'</sub> that the man asked about __<sub>1</sub> ] ] ?

In both questions, the question word *who* is intended to be interpreted as the object of the final preposition *about*. The popular explanation for why (1) is ok but the supposedly-synonymous (2) is bad is that (2) violates the Complex NP Constraint, which **bans extraction from a sentence dominated by a lexical noun phrase** (Ross 1967).

Why does a constraint on extraction rule out (2), a wh-question? Because one way of analyzing wh-questions is to assume that the wh-word is moved from its original position to the question-initial position, leaving a **gap**, i.e. an empty position at its original position. The original position of *who* in (1) and (2) is the object of *about*, and you can see that there is a gap there -- no material follows *about*. According to this movement analysis of wh-questions, *who* in (1) must have moved across two S' nodes and *who* in (2) must have moved across a S' node and then a NP node. This movement in (2) is what is ruled out by the Complex NP Constraint -- it bans extraction from a sentence, i.e. S', dominated by a lexical noun phrase, i.e. NP.

Complex NPs are also called **islands**, i.e. syntactic configurations from which extraction is not possible. There is an intuitive metaphor behind this naming -- you cannot move something out of an island. So the Complex NP Constraint is a kind of **island constraint**: it bans extraction out of an island.

So when people say some languages are sensitive to islands, what they mean is that certain kinds of extraction in these languages are sensitive to island constraints. For example, (2) shows that wh-question formation in English, a kind of movement (according to Chomskyan syntacticians), is sensitive to the Complex NP Constraint, a kind of island constraint.

However, not all syntacticians consider wh-question formation to be a movement transformation. For these syntacticians, island constraints are just constraints on legitimate dependencies. Wh-question is a kind of dependency: the wh-word *who* in (1) has a dependency with the gap after *about*, because it should be interpreted as if it were the object of *about*. Then, the Complex NP Constraint just bans a dependency across a sentence dominated by a lexical noun phrase.

The first chapter from this recent book by Chaves and Putnam (2021) has a pretty good theory-neutral introduction on island constraints from a cross-lingual perspective:
https://oxford.universitypressscholarship.com/view/10.1093/oso/9780198784999.001.0001/oso-9780198784999